# Nvidia Driver is capturing a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, nvidia-quadro, nvidia-settings

I've Nvidia NVS (Quadro) 4200M display driver (along with Intel HD Graphics3000) in my Dell Latitude e6420 laptop.

The Nvidia driver version is 22.21.13.8628 (in Nvidia Control Panel the driver version shows 386.28).

The problem is whenever I press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N key, Nview Desktop Manager Debug window appears. 
[image]

I've checked all settings under Nvidia Control Panel and Nvidia Desktop Manager, but couldn't find this keyboard shortcut. In Nvidia DT Manager, there is a tab for 'Hotkey Manager', but I've gone and checked all sub settings, and found that no option there has any keyboard shortcut assigned to it. How can I find which setting is blocking this keyboard shortcut?

Kindly help/guide.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had gotten the solution in the Nvidia Desktop Manager (I had assigned this shortcut to this).

But sorry that I no longer use that pc and have not that handy, I can't tell exact name and way of those steps/commands. But I did happen to find the same and switched that off.
What I learnt is that don't do something stupid or new in some preferences section (would rather call it jungle of preferences) unless you're fully sure what you're doing and also that you'd remember what you did!!